# Datatable querying: max and grouping

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I have a datatable as shown below:

[image]

From these I need to get the max of `statecountyid` based on the `source` and `sourcenickname` columns.

The result should be:

[image]

Comment: var maxRow = dtLPS.Select("statecountyid = MAX(statecountyid)");

Comment: I don't know if you can do it in one line of code, but one approach would be to create a `DataView` based on `source` and `sourcenickname`, assign it to the `DataTable` and then do your select.  Or are you trying to get the max `statecountyid` for each group of `source` and `sourcenickname`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
var result =
    from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new 
    {sourceKey = row["source"],sourcenicknamekey = row["sourcenickname"]} into g  
    select new
    { 
        maxSCIds = g.Max(x => x["statecountyid"])
    };
```